# SP.SOD.executeFunc is working only for admin user

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

When trying to get current logged in user using **CSOM** `SP.SOD.executeFunc` is not working and throws

> "Throw UnauthorizedAccessException"

in log but working fine with admin user. How to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
enter code here

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
       {

       SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup);



});</script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup()
{

 var grpName="HRAdmin";
             var userInGroup;
        var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

        var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
        currentContext.load(currentUser);

        var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
        currentContext.load(allGroups);

        var group = allGroups.getByName(grpName);alert("1");
        currentContext.load(group);alert("2");
        var groupUsers = group.get_users();alert("3");
        currentContext.load(groupUsers);alert("4");

        currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess, OnFailure);

        function OnSuccess(sender, args)
         {

            var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
            while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) 
            {

                var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
                if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) 
                {
                    userInGroup = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (userInGroup) 
            {
                alert("user exists in the group");
                //script to make your fields read only goes here
            }

            else
             {
                alert("user doestn't exist in the group");
           }

        }

        function OnFailure(sender, args)
         {
alert("Yes");
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Problem is not in `SP.SOD.executeFunc`. May in other code. Show your code

Comment: It could also be a publishing problem, is this JS file checked in as a major version and approved?

Comment: JS file is checked and published successfully.

Comment: I've updated my thread with code

Comment: Your other users do not have permission to query in `siteGroups` @samdaniel

Comment: Check whether the user has rights on the HRAdmin group. Specifically go to the group and check group settings , who can view the members of this group

Comment: Any help from my answer @samdaniel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user does not have permission to view the members of `HRAdmin`. So go to Group settings of `HRAdmin` and choose **Who can view the membership of the group?**

[image]

In your case it should be **Everyone**. Now try to run your code.